# How to stop JSONObject to convert my arrayList [3,4] in string "[3,4]"

Tags: java, android

1)This is the Code:

JSONObject myJson=new JSONObject();

```
try {

   List<Integer> myLists = new ArrayList<>();
   myLists.add(4);
   myLists.add(10);

   myJson.put("myLists",myLists);

} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.w("myJson", myJson);
```

2)This is the output in the console:

```
"myJson":"[4, 10]"
```

2)This is what I want in the console:

```
"myJson":[4, 10]                 (note the absence of quote "" around the array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
        myJson.put("myLists", new JSONArray(myLists));
```

Otherwise, if you pass ArrayList, or List this will be recognized as Object, not as something like Array, so toString() method will be used for putting it in JSON.